# Plotting geom_point and geom_lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a multilines plot by using `ggplot`. I also want to plot over the lines some points (which mean the significance). The problem is that when I use `geom_point`, these points do not coincide with the line that I want. These would be the data:

```
dat1: 
                1-4      2-5     3-6      4-7     5-8     6-9    7-10        id
 mod1      -0.035930 0.121970 0.34689 0.034345 0.35312 0.52048 0.58536     mod1
 mod2      -0.094121 0.297150 0.37262 0.512140 0.63918 0.42127 0.73890     mod2
 mod3       0.810550 0.876070 0.57120 0.472640 0.67341 0.79332 0.80882     mod3
 mod4      -0.121970 0.010009 0.49783 0.920100 0.76192 0.45662 0.45526     mod4

dat2:
             1-4     2-5 3-6    4-7     5-8     6-9    7-10        id
 mod1         NaN     NaN NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     mod1
 mod2         NaN     NaN NaN    NaN 0.63918     NaN     NaN     mod2
 mod3      0.81055 0.87607 NaN    NaN 0.67341 0.79332 0.80882    mod3
 mod5          NaN     NaN NaN 0.9201 0.76192     NaN     NaN    mod4
```

The plot will contain 4 lines and in the model with some values, I want to plot them with a point.

This is my try:

```
#Start Plotting
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
dat_r$id <- nam_model  #names of models
dat_r1$id <- nam_model
df <- melt(dat_r,id='id')
df2 <-melt(dat_r1,id='id')

p <-ggplot(df, aes(x=variable,y=value, group=id)) +
     geom_line(aes(color=id), lwd=1) + geom_point(aes(x=df2$variable,y=df2$value,      group=df$id),size = 4)
```

Any suggestion?? I appreciate any idea!

Thanks in advance

Comment: well you're using a different data frame for `geom_line` and `geom_point` Edit the question and add some details. What is `nam_model`? where did `dat_r` and `dat_r1` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read the data:

```
dat1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE, text="1-4      2-5     3-6      4-7     5-8     6-9    7-10        id
-0.035930 0.121970 0.34689 0.034345 0.35312 0.52048 0.58536     mod1
-0.094121 0.297150 0.37262 0.512140 0.63918 0.42127 0.73890     mod2
 0.810550 0.876070 0.57120 0.472640 0.67341 0.79332 0.80882     mod3
-0.121970 0.010009 0.49783 0.920100 0.76192 0.45662 0.45526     mod4")

dat2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE, text="1-4     2-5 3-6    4-7     5-8     6-9    7-10        id
 NaN     NaN NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     mod1
 NaN     NaN NaN    NaN 0.63918     NaN     NaN     mod2
 0.81055 0.87607 NaN    NaN 0.67341 0.79332 0.80882    mod3
 NaN     NaN NaN 0.9201 0.76192     NaN     NaN    mod4")
```

Than transform the data into long format with  the `reshape2` package:

```
library(reshape2)
df1 <- melt(dat1, id="id")
df2 <- melt(dat2, id="id")
```

You can also use a combination of the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- dat1 %>% gather(var, value, 1:7)
df2 <- dat2 %>% gather(var, value, 1:7)
```

Binding the data together in one dataframe (which is not necessarily):

```
dat <- cbind(df1,df2[,3])
names(dat) <- c("id","var","value1","value2")
```

Finally create the plot:

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=var, y=value1, color=id, group=id)) +
  geom_line(lwd=1) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=value2), size=4) +
  scale_x_discrete("\nModels") +
  scale_y_continuous("Value", breaks=c(0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8)) +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:
[image]

When you don't want to bind the data together in one dataframe, you can use:

```
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=var, y=value, color=id, group=id)) +
  geom_line(lwd=1) + 
  geom_point(data=df2, size=4) +
  scale_x_discrete("\nModels") +
  scale_y_continuous("Value", breaks=c(0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot for your help, it worked! nice plot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility:

Read data, using `check.names = FALSE` because your variable names are not syntactically valid.

```
dat1 <- read.table(text = "                1-4      2-5     3-6      4-7     5-8     6-9    7-10        id
 mod1      -0.035930 0.121970 0.34689 0.034345 0.35312 0.52048 0.58536     mod1
 mod2      -0.094121 0.297150 0.37262 0.512140 0.63918 0.42127 0.73890     mod2
 mod3       0.810550 0.876070 0.57120 0.472640 0.67341 0.79332 0.80882     mod3
 mod4      -0.121970 0.010009 0.49783 0.920100 0.76192 0.45662 0.45526     mod4",
                   header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

dat2 <- read.table(text = "             1-4     2-5 3-6    4-7     5-8     6-9    7-10        id
 mod1         NaN     NaN NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     mod1
 mod2         NaN     NaN NaN    NaN 0.63918     NaN     NaN     mod2
 mod3      0.81055 0.87607 NaN    NaN 0.67341 0.79332 0.80882    mod3
 mod5          NaN     NaN NaN 0.9201 0.76192     NaN     NaN    mod4",
                   header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

`melt` data to long format:

```
library(reshape2)
dat1m <- melt(dat1, id.var = "id")
dat2m <- melt(dat2, id.var = "id")
```

Plotting with data set for the lines, and another for the points:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df1m, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = id, group = id)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = df2m, size = 4)
```

[image]

A small note: in your `aes` call, avoid code like `dataset$variable` (e.g. `df2$value`). It may cause unwanted behaviour.